# how to insert data in Mysql from a Tkinter String Variable

Tags: python, mysql

i created 2 python script

in the 1st script i used tkinter to get the Entry of the user, then i created a button to submit  the entry, the button calls a function that calls the 2nd Script as a Module

the 2nd Script i created for the queries, i used Mysql-Python-Connector, in this script i created a function with a parameter, the parameter would be the Text Variable from the first Script.

The Problem: Everytime i run the Script this error pops up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "mainsoft.py", line 14, in insname
    querymod.dbins(nameget)
  File "/home/akeno/Documents/giveaway/redesign/main/stack/querymod.py", line 13, in dbins
    concursor.execute(querydb,aux)
  File "/home/akeno/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/akeno/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 598, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/akeno/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 486, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

**Heres the 1st Script:**

**mainsoft.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter


root = tkinter.Toplevel()

def insname():

    nameget = varname.get()

    import querymod

    querymod.dbins(nameget)    

namelb = Label(root, text = "Name")
namelb.pack()

varname = StringVar()

nameEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = varname)
nameEntry.pack()

submitButton = Button(root, command = insname)
submitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Heres the 2nd script, the query script:**

**querymod.py**

```
import mysql.connector

def dbins(param1):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'user1', password = 'yourpassword', host = '127.0.0.1', database = 'Student')

    concursor = con.cursor()

    aux = (param1)

    querydb = """insert into Student(Name) values(%s)"""

    concursor.execute(querydb,aux)

    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Any ideas how to solve this? thanks for reading.

Comment: Change this `aux = (param1)` to this `aux = (param1,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of :

```
aux = (param1)

querydb = """insert into Student(Name) values(%s)"""

concursor.execute(querydb,aux)
```

This :

```
aux = (param1)

querydb = "insert into Student(Name) values('{}')".format(aux)

concursor.execute(querydb)
```

Comment: isn't it insecure to use .format in this case, because in other post i read that this could allow sql injection, will it be fine if i use format or is there another way to fix this problem but using the (%s)? i want the database to be safe too.

Comment: I am using this format in one of my tkinter project. I faced no problems whatsoever.